# couchdb query timing out when run in a batch with continuous updates

Tags: java, database, nosql, couchdb, ektorp

I am using a simple batched fetch and update on couchdb.

```
    int batchSize = 5000;
    String startKey = "";
    List<FrontLineWorker> frontLineWorkers;

    while (true) {
        frontLineWorkers = allFrontLineWorkers.getMsisdnsFrom(startKey, batchSize);

        if (frontLineWorkers.size() < batchSize) break;

        for (FrontLineWorker frontLineWorker : frontLineWorkers) {
            // process record, only updates record
        }

        startKey = frontLineWorkers.get(frontLineWorkers.size() - 1).getMsisdn();
    }
```

The getMsisdnsFrom is a couch query, and it starts to time out after a few times. I know that couch indexes views only when a read is done, but since I only update the records it should not affect indexes. Also since this is an expected use, get a set of records, modify and get the next set, I don't expect it to time out.

I've tried with both batch times 1000 and 5000.

Exception message is : Exception in thread "main" org.ektorp.DbAccessException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

EDIT: It worked after I reduced the batch size to 100, but I would have preferred a higher batch size.

Answer (score 1):

This `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` is a pretty low-level exception, sounds like you might just need to increase the socket timeout value so that Java will wait for the read to complete.

[djc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158226/djc) is right too, all updates will cause re-indexing of the affected nodes, but the fact that you can avoid the timeout with a batch size of 100 means that the re-indexing is not causing a significant problem.

The problem is that the batch size is too large for your socket timeout, reduce the first or increase the second.

Comment: yes i know, but 100 is a very poor size for the database. I was wondering if there was a mistake in the way I was using it. But seems like that's the only option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Updating documents forces them to be reindexed.